# How to have an app get data from SP

Tags: 2013, app, sharepoint-on-prem

The company I work is currently looking at hosting information in our SP environment and having it accessed by an IOS app (app to be made). What is the feasibility with this concerning actually accessing the data (as well as pushing data from the app back to SP) as I have read that you can only use SharePoint's API's within SP, as well as how to provide user credentials in calls.

I know that SSIS can read data from SP (although I do not know how I would integrate it with an app).

Also from what I have read it seems that SP-hosted apps are simply programs that run in SP and as such are not an 'app', is this correct?